# Not able to find a good fit for a simple function with neural networks

Tags: deep-learning

I have been trying to adjust a neural network to a simple function: the mass of an sphere.
I have tried with different architectures, for example, a single hidden layer and two hidden layers, always with 128 neurons each, and training them for 5000 epochs.
The code is the usual one. Just in case, I publish one of them

```
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])
                        ,keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")
                        ,keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
history = model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=5000)
```

The results are shown in the graphs.

[image: two hidden layers, 128 neurons each]

[image: one hidden layer, 128 neurons]

I suspect that I am making an error somewhere, because I have seen that deep learning is able to match complex functions with much less epochs. I shall appreciate any hint to fix this problem and obtain a good fit with the deep learning function.

In order to make it clear I post the graph's code.

```
rs =[x for x in range(20)]
def masas_circulo(x):
    masas_circulos =[]
    rs =[r for r in range(x)]
    for r in rs:
        masas_circulos.append(model.predict([r])[0][0])

   return masas_circulos

 masas_circulos = masas_circulo(20) 
 masas_circulos
 esferas = [4/3*np.pi*r**3 for r in range(20)]
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.plot(rs,masas_circulos,label="DL")
 plt.plot(rs,esferas,label="Real");
 plt.title("Mass of an sphere.\nDL (1hl,128 n,5000 e) vs ground_truth")
 plt.xlabel("Radius")
 plt.ylabel("Sphere")
 plt.legend();
```

Comment: What are you trying to predict?: is it $V$ given $r$? for the formula $V=4/3\pi r^3$? if so, is it the output of your network, the single scalar, expected to be $V$? For me that seems like a plotting error: check how you are drawing the output of your network for different $r$

Comment: Ies, I am trying to predict V  given r for the formula  V=4/3πr^3. I have added the graphs' code.

Comment: Sphere's density=1 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to learn a cubic function that explodes in values and your issue is **scaling**. I have been able to learn a better approximation by scaling data and using **tanh** as activation function.

Code and result are as below:

[image]

Convergence around X=100 happens because of tanh activation. Relu will not work better because of negative values that is the result of scaling. You can try playing with **Leaky Relu** activation and various **alpha** values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def mass_of_sphere(R):
    return (4/3) * np.pi * (R**3)

X = np.linspace(1, 120, 500000)
y = [mass_of_sphere(x) for x in X]

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

scaler_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler_X.transform(X_test)

scaler_y = StandardScaler()
y_train = scaler_y.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test = scaler_y.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1),
                          keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "tanh"),
                          keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "tanh")])

early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 5)
model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mse')
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100, callbacks=[early_stopping], 
                    batch_size = 2048, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

y_hat = scaler_y.inverse_transform(model.predict(X_test)).reshape(-1)
y_test = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_test).reshape(-1)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 4))
ax.plot(sorted(scaler_X.inverse_transform(X_test).reshape(-1)), sorted(y_test), color = 'blue', label = 'Real')
ax.plot(sorted(scaler_X.inverse_transform(X_test).reshape(-1)), sorted(y_hat), color = 'orange', label = 'DL')
ax.legend()
```

Comment: Excellent. Rather surprising for me because I have read that relu should (almost) always work. For the moment I do not undersand the divergence with values bigger than 100. I will study your answer and try all your suggestions. I hope I shall be able to fit it beyond 100 :). I supposed that it was not neccesary to do any sort of "feature engineering", as is very frequently asserted. –

Comment: For better understanding, inspect tanh figure, it maps $(-\infty, \infty)$ to $(-1, 1)$. Having clarified that, inspect the scaled value of the mass of $R = 100$. 

scaler_y.transform(np.array([[mass_of_sphere(100)]]))

You can simply bypass this limitation by either changing activation function or using a higher range of training values, going for perhaps 500 instead of 120.

I just tested with values between (1, 500) and convergence occured at 400. Not an elegant solution but good to have.

Comment: I've got a very good fit using "elu" as an activation function. But I was surprised because comparing results (inside the range used) obtained from mass_of_sphere() and model.predict I found enourmous differences. For the moment, I do not identify the error

Comment: OK maybe a better approach: Scale your data using MinMaxScaler() to range(-1, 1) instead of StandardScaler(). Train your network with tanh activation in last layer again.
Don't forget to scale back your prediction.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler model seems to be the best option

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
xs = np.array([-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float)
ys2 = np.array([4/3*r*np.pi**3 for r in xs])    
model.fit(xs, ys2, epochs=500,validation_split=0.2)

def masa_circulo(x):
    return 4/3*x*np.pi**3
```

Testing it graphically

```
x = [x for x in range(1,int(1e6),int(1e3))]
y_masa_circulo = [ masa_circulo(m) for m in x]
y_masa_predicha= [model.predict([m])[0] for m in x]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
axes[0].plot(y_masa_circulo);
axes[0].set_title("y_masa_circulo")
axes[0].set_ylabel("y_masa_circulo")
axes[0].set_xlabel("Radio")

axes[1].plot(y_masa_predicha);
plt.title("y_masa_circulo")
plt.title("y_masa_predicha");
axes[1].set_ylabel("y_masa_predicha");
axes[1].set_xlabel("Radio");
```

[image: Graphical comparison function_results vs nn_results]

No need of scaling the data.